# How to show error message in the php contact form without reloading the entire page

Tags: php

I'm creating a contact form and I want to be able to display error without reloading the entire page, when the user doesn't write the email properly or leave the any of the required forms empty.
This the the code that I'm using
Thank you!

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['name'])));
        $email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['email'])));
        $message = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['message'])));
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/", $name)){
          $name_error = 'Invalid name';
        }
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/", $email)){
          $email_error = 'Invalid email';
        }
        if(strlen($message) === 0){
          $message_error = 'Your message should not be empty';
        }
      }
    ?>

 <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      <p><?php if(isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></p>

 <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
      <p><?php if(isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></p>

 <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
      <p><?php if(isset($message_error)) echo $message_error; ?></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($name_error) && !isset($subject_error) && !isset($email_error) && !isset($message_error)){
          $to = 'ex@myemail.com'; // edit here
          $body = " Name: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
          if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
            echo '<p style="color: green">Message sent</p>';
          }else{
            echo '<p>Error occurred, please try again later</p>';
          }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: use JavaScript or ajax

Comment: You may find [MDN Form data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) an interesting (and valuable) read.